# Calculate skip and take for paging

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, pagination

I am trying to convert data that I got back as PagedResult into PagedData that uses skip and take for paging:

```
eg:
For page1 – skip: 0, take: 25
For Page2 – skip: 25, take:25
For Page3 – skip: 50, take:25
and so on...
```

I used the following conversion to calculate skip and take:

```
skip --- Convert.ToInt32((Result.CurrentPage-1)*Result.ItemsPerPage),
take --- Convert.ToInt32(Result.ItemsPerPage));
```

However, the above logic is not working for calculating skip. Can someone please help me correct the logic?

Comment: Can you elaborate on who it's `not working`? It looks fine.

Comment: I'm assuming Result.CurrentPage is 1 when you're on the first page (as opposed to being 0)?